# how to add my internal HDD as a USB HDD in vmware or virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

I want to connect my internal HDD on my laptop to vmware or virtualbox as a usb drive and not an internal HDD drive. How can I do that?
The reason for doing this is that I have a program that only works on usb devices and I don't want to take out my internal HDD.

Comment: Does this program wants access to full HDD or just some folders? Full host HDD access from virtual machine is probably not a good idea and very hard hack to achieve.

Comment: full HDD access is needed